# "Long have we waited for this day "Long we have waited for this day."

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct? Normally its subject verb and this is not a question but I still think the first option is correct and possibly even better.Why?

Comment: Either is possible.

Comment: This is not everyday English. What is the context? If you can bring your question into scope, someone may be able to provide a more considered answer.

Comment: "Long have we waited for this day." Anything with for I guess. Or an adverb "Long have we waited, now its time."

Comment: You need to edit your question. You know the rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

English has a strong preference to put the verb second in declarative sentences (the second element, not necessarily the second word). This means that if something other than the subject precedes the verb, there is a tendency to invert the verb and the subject:

> Long **have I** waited for this day.
>
> Never **had he** seen such a thing before.
>
> On no account **should you** approach him.

Sentences like these are rather literary: in normal speech you would not start with the adverb, eg "I have waited a long time for this day".

Note: all this does not apply when the element at the start is a linking item, such as "and", "otherwise", "or else".

> Otherwise **you can** wait.

It also doesn't apply when the item is not in the same breath group (usually set off with a comma in writing):

> In any event, **that's** my answer.